# Shiny module error: Error in paste(namespace, collapse = ns.sep) : cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

Tags: r, shiny, shinymodules

I am new to modules and have read the mastering shiny sections as well as researched this error related to shiny modules pretty well but not found anything that explains or solves why the error is occurring in my particular case.

I am trying to pass two reactives to the module and use them as data in constructing a leaflet map.

Note that the map code and filters worked fine before I extracted the map stuff into a module, so I know that code isn't the issue. I think it has something to do with trying to pass reactive data into the module, but what I've read suggests that this is possible and no different than passing fixed data.

**map module**

```r
mapUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  leafletOutput(ns("map"))
}

mapServer <- function(id, data) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
   output$map <- renderLeaflet({
      data() %>% 
        leaflet() %>%
        addPolygons(popup = ~data()$popup_content)

    })
  })
}
```

**Simplified App**

```r
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)


ui = fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    selectInput(inputId = "media",
                   choices = choices_map_type,
                   label = "Select media to display",
                   selected = "A",
                   multiple = F),
    
    mapUI("map")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data <- read_csv("whatever.csv")
  states <- read_rds("states_sf.rds") #US states shapefile
  
  mapServer(id, data = map_pw())
  
  filt_data <- reactive({data %>%
      filter(media == input$media) 
  }) #There are inputs i'm leaving out of the UI for brevity
  
  map_pw <- reactive({ states %>%
      left_join(filt_pw())
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

```
Error in paste(namespace, collapse = ns.sep) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
```

I have also tried a number of variations on this.  Including passing the reactives with and without `()`, using both `data` and `data()` at the start of the `renderLeaflet()` chain, and all give the same error.

Comment: Try with `mapServer(id, data = map_pw)`, i.e. pass the `reactive` itself instead of its "content".

Comment: I tried that, but I get the same error. I also tried changing the `data() %>%...` line in the mapServer definition in the module to be `data` in conjunction with your suggestion.  All produce the same error.

Comment: Second look. The issue is that you use `id` (which actually is a function from dplyr). Try with `mapServer("map", data = map_pw)` and keep `data()` inside the module server.

Comment: That was it! Feel free to submit as an answer.